# Доступ к одной папке с разными правами

Tags: ftp, samba, debian

```
/home   SAMBA group nobody user nobody  777
```

Задача: допустить FTP пользователя (например, group: ftpgroup, user: fu1в эту-же папку но с правами read only).

*Система Debian. Варианты с биндом диска с усеченными правами и переопределение прав на симлинк не прошли :(*

Comment: через fuse можно попробовать проксировать, либо какой-нить ftp server типа proftpd может работать с виртуальными юзерами

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте поменять права на директорию (рекурсивно) SAMBA group nobody user nobody 777 на 744.